# Why does rails 3.1 and 3.2.0.rc2 create an application.css instead of an scss?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When a rails app is created with rails 3.1 or 3.2.0.rc2 it by default creates an `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` file, however each controller/model created there after creates an `app/assets/stylesheets/<controller or model name>.scss`.

Why isn't an `application.scss` created by default?

How do you properly incorporate an `application.scss` and get rid of the `application.css` entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just rename it to `application.scss` and then you can import in your other `.scss` files like this:

```
// Inside application.scss

// HTML Reset
@import "reset.scss";

// Users CSS
@import "users.scss";
```

When you compile the SCSS, it will generate the `application.css` for you from all of the other imported files or CSS within that file.

Answer (score 1):

`application.css` just plays like a house keeper, it represents the correct order of other `.scss` files.

Put the real working CSS in `application.css` may not good practice, as the comment generated by rails below:

> You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll
>   appear at the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to
>   create a new file per style scope.